# which one is the correct one in colloquial sentences?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

so a friend of mine asked me a question in how to say that "i were just about to finish up the game" but he got confused in how to say it in a colloquial sentence. so which one is the correct one ?

- i just about to finish up the game
- i just about to finishing up the game

Comment: We were...   I was.... I am...  We are...  just about to finish up the game.   They all work.  None of yours do.

Answer (score 1):

> I was just about to finish up the game

I was just about to finish the game when my friend came up and was unable to describe that I was just about to finish the game.